# VBA MsgBox to close in less than one second

Tags: vba, ms-word

I've got a script of closing a `MsgBox` automatically after a given amount of seconds:

```
Sub Test1()
Dim AckTime As Integer, InfoBox As Object
Set InfoBox = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
AckTime = 3
Select Case InfoBox.Popup("Click OK or do nothing within 3 seconds.", _
AckTime, "This is your Message Box", 0)
Case 1, -1
Exit Sub
End Select
End Sub
```

Problem is, I'd like the box to close in less than a full second, perhaps half a second, but changing it to `.5`, for example, doesn't do anything. In fact, I don't think it closes at all.

Comment: have a read of this http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=24610

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry but Windows Script Host method Popup takes only integer as delay parameter, [source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x83z1d9f%28v=vs.84%29.aspx).